# Facebook oauth error=access_denied in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook-oauth

Facebook is giving me error=access_denied, while using facebook oauth in my project
Here is ,my code :

```
var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "---",
            AppSecret = "---",
            BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
            UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,email"
        };


        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

and FacebookBackChannelHandler.js :

```
namespace naah2.Facebook
 {
 public class FacebookBackChannelHandler : HttpClientHandler
 {
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage>
        SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
                  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/oauth"))
        {
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(
                request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("?access_token", "&access_token"));
        }
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I was having this issue 1 week ago, By searching the solution online I came to know that I was using facebook provider 3.0.1 which have this problem so I updated it to 3.1.0 and it started working. But somehow from last 2 days I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use back channel handler anymore.
Install Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook -Version 4.0.0 (latest till date)

In `Startup.Auth.cs`,

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            appId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
            appSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        );
```

That's it, you don't need other infos, and delete BackChannelHandler class file

Comment: Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook -Version 4.0.0 is installed. The "await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()" is returning null.

Facebook Api is version 3.0